# How to use StreamBuilder in Drawer?

Tags: android, flutter

I am implementing a Logout widget that will only appear when user is logged in.
I used this `DrawerLogout` widget inside a `Drawer` with a `ListView`

```
class DrawerLogout extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DrawerLogoutState createState() => _DrawerLogoutState();
}

class _DrawerLogoutState extends State<DrawerLogout> {
  Stream authState = FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: authState,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'Logout',
                style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).errorColor),
              ),
              onTap: () {
                FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
              },
            );
          }
          return Container();
        });
  }
}
```

Something like this:

```
Scaffold(
drawer: Drawer(
child: ListView(
   children:[
             ...
             ...
             DrawerLogout(),
            ])
          )
         )
```

The problem is the logout button only shows for the first time when I open the drawer, after closing the drawer and reopen it, the logout button disappear.

This is the error code when it disappear:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Cannot add new events while doing an addStream
```

Comment: Does initializing this `Stream authState = FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges();` in `initState()` help?

Comment: @JoyTerence it works! Thank you very much! Could you use an Answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, moving the state initialization to `initState` solved the issue.

The issue was caused by new events being added into a disposed stream. As per docs:

> If a State's build method depends on an object that can itself change state, for example a ChangeNotifier or Stream, or some other object to which one can subscribe to receive notifications, then be sure to subscribe and unsubscribe properly in initState, didUpdateWidget, and dispose:
>
> - In initState, subscribe to the object.
> - In didUpdateWidget unsubscribe from the old object and subscribe to the new one if the updated widget configuration requires replacing the object.
> - In dispose, unsubscribe from the object.

Answer (score 0):

As @JoyTerence suggested, initializing the stream in initState works!

```
class DrawerLogout extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DrawerLogoutState createState() => _DrawerLogoutState();
}

class _DrawerLogoutState extends State<DrawerLogout> {
  Stream authState;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    authState = FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: authState,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'Logout',
                style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).errorColor),
              ),
              onTap: () {
                FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
              },
            );
          }
          return Container();
        });
  }
}
```